# Enviar datos de una tabla en un modal a una tabla php usando php y jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Tengo un modal de bootstrap al cual cargo datos desde mi base de datos en mysql lo que quiero que haga, es que al darle en el boton agregar me agregue el producto de la fila del modal a una tabla en php en otra pagina y al darle en otro producto me agregue el siguiente y asi sucesivamente. Lo que hace ahora es cargar el primer dato que le envió y después al cargar el segundo elimina el que anteriormente envié, entonces lo que deseo es que haga una lista. Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Este es el modal.
[image: Este es el modal.]

Lo que necesito es que me envie los datos de la fila aqui, en esta tabla Pero al enviar el primer dato el siguiente borra el primero como si se actualizará. Lo que necesito es que los liste.

[image: Lo que necesito es que me envie los datos de la fila aqui, en esta tabla]

Les adjunto el código del archivo agregar.php

```
<?php
require_once("../clases/conexion.php");
$id = $_POST['codigo'];
$c = $_POST['canti'];
$sql = "select * from tbl_producto where codigo = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
?>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
  <th class='text-center'>CODIGO</th>
  <th class='text-center'>CANT.</th>
  <th>DESCRIPCION</th>
  <th class='text-right'>PRECIO UNIT.</th>
  <th class='text-right'>PRECIO TOTAL</th>  
  </tr>
  <?php    
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     $codigo=$row['codigo'];
     $producto=$row['nombre'];
     $marca=$row['marca'];
     $precio=$row['precio'];
     $preciofinal = $precio*$c;
  ?>
  <tr>
   <td class="text-center"><?php echo $codigo; ?></td>
   <td class="text-center"><?php echo $c; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $producto.' '.$marca; ?></td>
   <td class="text-right"><?php echo $precio; ?></td>
   <td class="text-right"><?php echo $preciofinal; ?></td>
   <td class='text-center'><a href="#" onclick=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></td>    
   </tr>
  <?php
    }
  ?>
 <tr>
  <td class='text-right' colspan=4>SUBTOTAL $</td>
  <td class='text-right'></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class='text-right' colspan=4>IGV $</td>
   <td class='text-right'></td>
  <td></td> 
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td class='text-right' colspan=4>TOTAL $</td>
 <td class='text-right'></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Esta es la funcion con la cual le envio los datos para la consulta

```
function agregar(id){  
 var cant = document.getElementById('cantidad_'+id).value;
      $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "servlet/agregaraPHP.php",
      data: "codigo="+id+"&canti="+cant,
      success: function (r){
      $("#resultados1").html(r);
      }                                
      });
      }
```

Y este es el códgio del modal bootstrap

```
     <!-- Modal Busca Producto-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="AgregarPro" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Buscar productos</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">                                              
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filtrar" placeholder="Buscar productos">
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="bus"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></i> Buscar</a>
                  </div>
                </form>                 
                                  <div class="outer_div">                                          
                                      <?php
                                        require './clases/conexion.php';
                                        $sql = "select * from tbl_producto";
                                        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                                      ?>       
                                        <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table">
                                            <tbody class="buscar">    
                                        <tr  class="warning">
                                            <th>Código</th>
                                            <th>Producto</th>
                                            <th>Marca</th>  
                                            <th><span class="pull-right">Cant.</span></th>
                                            <th><span class="pull-right">Precio</span></th>
                                            <th class='text-center' style="width: 36px;">Agregar</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php
                                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                            $codigo=$row['codigo'];
                                            $producto=$row['nombre'];
                                            $marca=$row['marca'];
                                            $cantidad=$row['cantidad'];
                                            $precio=$row['precio'];                                            
                                        ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><?php echo $codigo; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $producto; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $marca; ?></td>
                                            <td class='col-xs-1'>
                                                <div class="pull-right">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-align:right" id="cantidad_<?php echo $codigo; ?>" value="<?php echo $cantidad; ?>">
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class='col-xs-2'>
                                                <div class="pull-right">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-align:right" id="precio" value="<?php echo $precio; ?>">
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class='text-center'>
                                                <a class='btn btn-info'href="#" onclick="agregar(<?php echo $codigo; ?>)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php    
                                        }               
                                        ?>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        </div>
                                  </div><!-- Datos ajax Final -->
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>                  
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Por favor, les agradezco por su ayuda.

Comment: no veo tu `id resultados1`... pero en principio te puedo decir es que con  `$("#resultados1").html(r)` borras todo el contenido de ese elemento... quizás deberías usar: [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/).... `$("#resultados1").append(r)`

Comment: Esta es la funcion para enviar datos por ajax

Comment: function agregar(id){  
     var cant = document.getElementById('cantidad_'+id).value;
     $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: "servlet/agregaraPHP.php",
     data: "codigo="+id+"&canti="+cant,
     success: function (r){
     $("#resultados1").html(r);
     }                                
     });
     }

Comment: Probe lo que me dijiste pero sigue igual, me borra el primer campo que añadi y coloca el segundo. Agradezco tu ayuda

Comment: *"al darle en el boton agregar me agregue el producto de la fila del modal a una tabla en php en otra pagina"*. ¿Quieres decir qué tienes dos pestañas: A y B, en A está el modal y presionas "agregar" y en la pestaña B debe de reflejarse en tiempo real? ¿O están en la misma página?

Comment: Colega para esto necesitarias hacer un submit de el o los input de cada item en la tabla que necesites guardar y lo guardas como cualquier formulario comun y corriente, te recomendaria usar algo de JavaScript para enviar el formulario sin recargar la pagina, de esa forma al agregar productos automaticamente se hara un post a un archivo php donde guardes esa info

Comment: Hola GuzGarcia, digamos que tengo una pagina A y ahí hay un boton agregar productos este boton hace que nos aparezca un modal en el cual esta la lista de productos, cada fila de producto al final tiene un boton para agregar el producto seleccionado, al presionar este boton el producto selecionado carga en una tabla en la pagina A en tiempo real. Al añadir otro producto a la pagina A se borra el que ya añadi anteriormente entonces quiero saber como puedo hacer que no se borre si no que se añada, nada mas y se puedan seguir añadiendo mas productos. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas, antes de nada comentar que hoy en día no es muy "atractivo" hacerlo de esta manera, PHP no puede mostrar el contenido más que cuando se renderiza la página al recargar, por lo que mínimo **va a tener que hacer una recarga por cada producto que agreges**.

Tras leer el código veo que tu función de ajax envía un único id (y no la colección de los actuales + el nuevo), por lo que se pierden los anteriores y no mostrará más que un resultado, en el `for` sólo entrará en una ocasión.

Hay **varias formas de solucionarlo** mi recomendación es la siguiente: Primero crearía un pequeño script PHP que te devuelva la info de cada producto

```
require_once("../clases/conexion.php");

function getProducto($id) {
    $id = $_POST['codigo'];
    $c = $_POST['canti'];
    $sql = "select * from tbl_producto where codigo = '$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)

    // Generamos un array de respuesta
    $codigo=$row['codigo'];
    $producto=$row['nombre'];
    $marca=$row['marca'];
    $cantidad=$row['cantidad'];
    $precio=$row['precio'];

    $arrayProducto = array (
        'codigo' => $row['codigo'],
        'nombre' => $row['nombre'],
        ...
    );

    return json_encode($arrayProducto);
}
```

Con esto y tu función ajax (cambiando la línea url a la dirección del anterior script, ej: `url: "loquesea/getproducto.php"`) podrás recoger la info de cada producto e ir agregándolos a la tabla.

Ejemplo:

```
$('#tu-tabla tbody').append('<tr><td>' + result.codigo + '</td><td> ' + result.nombre ...
```

Así podrás ir agregando productos de forma dinámica, le he puesto un id (#tu-tabla) para poder diferenciarla de la otra u otras que puedas tener + la etiqueta  dentro de cada tabla para poder manejar el contenido sin afectar al encabezado ni al resumen.

---

Otra opción es **copiar la info directamente de la primera tabla** si tienes toda la que necesitas tener en la segunda (como creo que es así en éste caso).

Primero obtienes la info de la línea en la cual pulsaste el botón agregar:
Le añades a ese `<a>` una clase para poder invocar el evento desde código y no inline, obteniendo así el evento:

```
$('.agregar-producto').click(function (e) {
    var line = $(e.currentTarget).parent().parent().parent(); // Hasta llegar al <tr> raíz de la línea vamos..
    var result = {
        codigo: line.find('td')[0].text(),
        ...
        cantidad: line.find('input[name="cantidad"]').val()
        ...
    }
}
```

Tras ello guardamos el objeto result en un array que representará el contenido de la tabla `tablaResumen.push('claveProducto', result);` poniéndole como clave el id de cada producto. Haciéndolo así tienes la ventaja de que cada vez que agregues más de una vez el mismo producto puedes comprobar si ya existe en la lista y de estarlo, simplemente sumas la cantidad a la ya existente en lugar de añadir una nueva línea para el mismo producto.

Existen muchos muchos más detalles que añadir a esta pequeña app, como la recomendación de una función tipo `refrescarTabla()` que utilice la lista de objetos guardada para pintar exactamente lo que contiene tras agregar/eliminar un producto, pero eso ya no es el contexto de la pregunta.

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Guardalo en una variable por lado del cliente, y cuando este listo lo envias.
Puedes guardar la data de la tabla en una sessionStorage o localStorage. Este es un archivo temporal que se crea en el pc del usuario y tiene un max de tamaño de 5mb. la diferencia entre sessionStorage y localStorage es que una vez que cierras el navegador sessionStorage pierder todos los datos, y localStorage no.

Para poder invocar y llamar a esta funcion para guardar datos, basta con colocar lo siguiente:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("tabla", datoTabla);
localStorage.setItem("tabla", datoTabla);
```

En este caso guardaras el dato ya lista de la tabla en "datoTabla" para luego crear la variable session o local, en la variable "tabla". Si deseas guardar cada vez que vaya ingresando, pues llamas a la session o a la local, y le sumas el codigo que necesitas, si dibujas la tabla, vale decir:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("tabla",sessionStorage.getItem("tabla") + datoTabla);
localStorage.setItem("tabla",localStorage.getItem("tabla") + datoTabla);
```

para rescatar los valores puedes hacerlo con:

```
sessionStorage.getItem("tabla");    
localStorage.getItem("tabla");
```

y para eliminar solo basta con

```
sessionStorage.removeItem("tabla");
localStorage.removeItem("tabla");
```

Espero que te ayuda, exito :D